# How to make row take all available height

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I try to make a layout like this:
the column that takes 100% of the height inside:

- Row with fixed height (3em)
- A second row that will take any space possible - from almost 100% to 0
- third row: again fixed height (3em)

---

I want to obtain similar result to github project view where space for tasks/issues will change height dynamically but header and add item button have always fixed height:

[image: everything is fitting]

[image: some task dont fit - scroll bar is shown]

[image]

[image]

---

Problem is that I am doing this program mainly as a backend project and frontend is not my strong suit, thus I may make stupid mistakes and cannot express what is my problem here. My solution (that didn't worked) looked like that:

```css
.issue-board .state-column {
  background-color: aquamarine;
  min-width: 15em;
  max-width: 15em;
}

.issue-board .state-column-header {
  background-color: azure;
  height: 3em;
}

.issue-board .state-issues {
  background-color: beige;
  height: 80%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.issue-board .state-add-issue {
  background-color: bisque;
  height: 3em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="col-3 state-column border-1 border-primary h-100">
  <div class="container-fluid h-100">
    <div class=" row flex-shrink-0 state-column-header border-bottom border-primary justify-text-center m-2">
      <div class="col">
        <h3>New</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row flex-shrink-1 state-issues">
      <div class="col overflow-auto">
        <ul>
          <li>dsafadsf</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row flex-shrink-0 state-add-issue">
      <div class="col">
        <button class="btn">Add Item</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-3 state-column border-1 border-primary h-100">
  <div class="d-flex flex-column h-100">
    <div class="flex-shrink-0 state-column-header m-2">
      <h3>New</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-shrink-1 state-issues">
      <ul>
        <li>dsafadsf</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-shrink-0 state-add-issue">
      <button class="btn">Add Item</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please revise the demo above to show your attempt. It should probably contain just one HTML snippet.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem when you try to make a row to take the full height is that its parent doesn't have a proper height. The best way to do it is to create a proper layout knowing the size of all your elements and make the height of your main container adapt based on the other components.
Then put your container's display to flex with an "align-items: stretch;" so that the children element will take all available height.

Here's an example of **one (simple) way** to do so.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #0E1117;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
header {
    padding: 20px;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 0;
}
.container {
    height: calc(100vh - 160px);
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    padding: 50px;
}
.item {
    background-color: #020408;
    border: 1px solid #13161C;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 300px;
}
.item > div {
    flex: 1;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
button {
    all: initial;
    color: #727982;
    font-family: inherit;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <h1>A header</h1>
</header>
<div class="container">
    <div class="item">
        <h3>No Status</h3>
        <div></div>
        <button>+ Add card</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't leverage the Bootstrap library, which it should. Also, questions are expected to be more specific, and this one really shouldn't be answered. Please see [ask] and [answer].